# sublime text 3 regular expression grouping

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a text file with a series of numbers with many decimal digits and want to only keep the first 2 decimal places.

Sample numbers:
`57.0977452, 56.11753043, 55.16086013, 54.22551611, 53.3095779,`

The regular expression used to capture all the decimal digits after the second one:
`\.[0-9]{2}([0-9]*),`

Sublime Text is just getting everything ignoring the (grouping).
Is there a setting I need to change or that's just how Sublime Text works?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are capturing the last part `\.[0-9]{2}([0-9]*),` but you want to capture (to keep) the first part.

You could match `(\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+,` and replace with capture group 1 like `$1`

The quantifier here is `+` to match 1 or more digits.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rd9izq/1)

If there have to be leading digits, you might also match those and use `\K` to forget what is matched so far, and match `\b\d+\.\d\d\K\d+,`

Then leave the replacement field empty.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9Oyty/1)

[image]

If you want to match them instead of replacing, you can assert optional digits followed by a `,` to the right using a positive lookahead.

```
\b\d+\.\d\d(?=\d*,)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kMqgWg/1)

[image]

Comment: I've never seen `\K` before (granted, I'm no regex guru, but I manage). I'm definitely adding it to my toolbox!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try look-behind pattern: `(?<=\.\d{2})(\d+,)`

This pattern will capture all the decimal digits after the second one.

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/RMGvgF/1).